# COSMOS db - none of the autoscale or RU settings are available to me

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've been reading all the docs on RU's and throughput, all seems to make sense.
For some reason though, I have no option to

1. set RU's when I create a database or container
2. update RU's after creating database or container
3. choose autoscale

The "Settings and Scale" option (that I see in the help docs) under a container only reads "Settings" for me.

I'm on a Pay-As-You-Go it says under my subscription. I'm using southern UK region. Could this be it? Who knows. Very frustrating.

Comment: Accompanying such a  question with snapshots of what you're actually seeing will help.

Comment: @AnupamChand I think I've found the problem, I set my capacity mode to Serverless!